# Can't find module [X] or it's corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I was sent a zip file from a github repo's master branch and opened up on my machine in vscode. When I view any of the typescript files all of the items that are being imported are throwing errors. When I hover my mouse over the error I see 'Can't find module [X] or it's corresponding type declarations'.

I've tried setting the 'TypeScript: Select TypeScript version' in vscode using 'cmd + shift + p' and it doesn't solve it.

Screenshot of vscode here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/areBu.png

Comment: Have you done an `npm install` to obtain the dependencies seen in the import directives?

Comment: This was too obvious.. Good catch! Problem solved. Thanks for the reminder of the 1st thing that should be done when cloning down a repo.. Installing any dependencies that exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.